Write the Kalman state vector update equation into the form $Ax=b$
I was reading an old article on Kalman Filters (https://doi.org/10.1109/TAC.1983.1103242),
and they state that the state vector corrector equation:
$$\hat x = \bar x + PH^T (HPH^T+R)^{-1} (z-H\bar x)$$
can be rewritten into an $Ax=b$ form.
They present the following "mathematically equivalent" equation:
$$(P^{-1} + H^TR^{-1}H)\hat x = P^{-1} \bar x + H^TR^{-1}z$$
However, I am unable to connect the dots on how to transform the first equation to the second.
I tried to play with the Woodbury matrix identity, but it seems to go nowhere...
Any idea?
Matrices dimensions and properties:

$\hat x$, $\bar x$ are $1\times n$.
$z$ is $1\times m$.
$P$ is $n\times n$ and (semi-)defined positive.
$R$ is $m\times m$ and (semi-)defined positive.
$H$ is $m\times n$.


See (7) and (8) on p. 7 here: https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Identification/Kalman_filter/ATI_kalman_slides.pdf

Possibly more informative: for $\hat{x}$ in the second equation, substitute the right-hand side in the first equation and simplify vigorously until you arrive at something obviously true.  Then the derivation is what you just did, in reverse.

@EricTowers Thanks. I wasn't able to make it work at first, until seeing there were typos in the slide :d
With the gain expression proof, it's straightforward to go from the first to the second equation.
If you don't mind, I'll write the answer, thanks again!

We first need the following equality:
$$\begin{align}
H^T &= H^T\\
H^T R^{-1} H P H^T + H^T &= H^T + H^T R^{-1} H P H^T \\
H^T R^{-1} (H P H^T + R) &= (P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H) P H^T\\
H^T R^{-1} &= (P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H) P H^T (H P H^T + R)^{-1}
\end{align}$$
Then multiplying
$$\hat x = \bar x + PH^T (HPH^T + R)^{-1} (z-H\bar x)$$
by $(P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)$ gives
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
(P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H) \hat x &= (P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H) \bar x \\&\qquad+ \underbrace{(P^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)PH^T (HPH^T + R)^{-1}}_{H^TR^{-1}} (z-H\bar x)\\
&= P^{-1} \bar x  + \cancel{H^TR^{-1}H\bar x} + H^TR^{-1} z - \cancel{H^TR^{-1}H\bar x}
\end{align}$$
